# Looking for freeware application for screen and audio recording

Tags: recording, screen-capture, video-capture, audio-recording

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Record screen without lag](https://superuser.com/questions/39886/record-screen-without-lag)
>   [Free, cross-platform screen recording utility](https://superuser.com/questions/143698/free-cross-platform-screen-recording-utility)
>   [Free desktop recording / screencasting on windows](https://superuser.com/questions/201/free-desktop-recording-screencasting-on-windows)

Hey,

I am creating video tutorials for my blog, and for that purpose looking for a freeware application, which I can use to record video of screen as well as audio at the same time.

kindly help me on this.

Thanks

Comment: To sum up, use the search function or just look through the list of suggested similar topics after you enter the title of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) fits the bill. It appears you are using Windows from your other questions on the site.

> CamStudio is able to record **all screen
>   and audio activity on your computer**
>   and create industry-standard AVI video
>   files and using its built-in SWF
>   Producer can turn those AVIs into
>   lean, mean, bandwidth-friendly
>   Streaming Flash videos (SWFs)